# Soundcloud API 401 Unauthorized When Using /resolve

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm using the 'Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen' method of authentication (see http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication). That's the method where you provide the whole shebang of credentials -- client_id, client_secret, username, and password. I'm also using the Ruby SDK.

```
# create client object with app and user credentials
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                        :client_secret => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
                        :username => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
                        :password => 'YOUR_PASSWORD')
```

I am trying to use the client to resolve a user.

```
puts client.get('/resolve', :url => 'https://soundcloud.com/random-username').inspect
```

However, I keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` returned by the client.

I can confirm that I am authenticating, because the following executes fine.

```
puts client.get('/me').username
```

Does anyone have any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that you need to include your `client_id` in every request.

```
puts client.get('/resolve', :url => 'https://soundcloud.com/random-username', client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
```